# Can producer send offset fetch request in kafka?

Tags: message-queue, apache-kafka

This is with regards to the use case of letting a *Producer* know if the message has been consumed by the *Consumer*.

My idea is that every time a message is consumed, *Consumer* commits the offset and the *Producer* can track and read current offsets to see if corresponding messages were consumed.

Also, please don't hesitate to let me know if this is the right way to handle the use case as I have no experience in Kafka. I know Kafka is not designed to work this way (handling the above use case) but I have to persist with Kafka.

Comment: What version are you using? How do you plan to make the Producer find out about the offset?

Comment: I can use the latest version if the need be. I was thinking of using kafka API to fetch offset in the same way as [consumer does it](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is the title, the answers is no, at least in the latest version of kafka 0.9.0.1 there is no way to know what is the offset for a partition from the producer.

Comment: I can see a way to read offsets via api call to offset manager as evident [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka). You mean I can not consume the same API from producer?

Comment: can you help me clarify why similar api import statements won't work with the producer?

Comment: similiar api import statements? what?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I can see the kafka api to support offset fetch request through an api call (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetFetchRequest)). As mentioned above, I see an implementation example of the same [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka). Just to confirm on your answer, do you mean the same api calls are not available for the producer?

Comment: Yes, from the Producer Api there is no way to do fetch requests.